# Javascript regex match *not* start of line

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd consider myself adept at understanding regular expressions; for the first time, I've been stumped, and the last 20 minutes of googling/searching SO for the answer has yielded nothing.

Consider the string:

```
var string = "Friends of mine are from France and they love to frolic."
```

And I want to replace or capture (or do something with) every occurrence of "fr" (case insensitive).

I could use, simply:

```
var replaced = string.replace(/fr/gi);
```

However, what if I wanted to ignore the very first occurrence of "fr"? Ordinarily I'd use a positive lookbehind (say, `(?<=.)fr` in php) to do this but our friend javascript doesn't do that. Without installing a third party library, is there any way to ensure my expression does NOT match at the start of line?

**Update:** While there are means of replacing with the captured `$1`, my particular use-case is `split()` here, and would require fixing up the array after the fact if I used something like @Explosion Pills' suggestion `string.replace(/^(fr)|fr/gi, "$1");`

Comment: When no lookbehind, match it in a subpattern and add it back in: `replace(/(.)fr/gi,'$1andthensomereplace')`.

Comment: @Wrikken my actual use-case here is `split()` -- I need to split on a complex expression, so how would I add that back in on a split?

Comment: @r3mus what array are you looking for?  What do you mean by recompiling after the fact?

Comment: @ExplosionPills hard to explain, but if I split out the "fr" with a preceding character, I'd have to capture those erroneously stripped characters back in the split array somehow.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
string.split(/(?!^)fr/gi);
```

This leaves you with `["Friends of mine are ", "om ", "ance and they love to ", "olic."]`

Answer (score 5):

You could just go the path of least resistence and use capturing/alternation:

```
string.replace(/^(fr)|fr/gi, "$1");
```

Comment: As I wrote to @Wrikken, my actual use-case here is split() -- I need to split on a complex expression, so how would I add that back in on a split?

Comment: @r3mus you may want to update your question since that could substantially change the answer.  If you have a capture group with `split`, the captured pattern is included as a result.  Replace the above with `.split` to see what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, done. Good point. Still, great suggestion for whenever I'm *not* using `split()`.

Answer (score 2):

I might try `/(?!^)fr/gi`.  Basically, only match where a beginning-of-string assertion wouldn't pass.

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "Friends of mine are from France and they love to frolic."
var replaced;
if(string.substr(0, 2).toLowerCase() == "fr"){
replaced = string.substr(0, 2)+string.substr(2).replace(/fr/gi);
}
else{
replaced = string.replace(/fr/gi);
}
```

Comment: I might be reading this wrong, but aren't you effectively chopping off the first `Fr`?  That's part of the data; you don't get to just rip it out without putting it back somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "Friends of mine are from France and they love to frolic."
var replaced = string.replace(/(.)fr/gi,'$1||').split('||')
```